# Numpy Array: Count values that are in a line (from an Image)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I have several black (=1) and white (=0) images in NumPy. I would like **count the number of times the ones are in a straight line in all 2D directions**.

As soon as the ones are not in a row anymore I'd like to stop counting. I need to count from both sides of the line. The idea is to be able to extract how long the line is straight from one side compared to how long it is straight from the other.

Please look at the following MWE which, I hope, will explain my problem better.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

background = np.zeros((60,60))

one = background.copy() # straight line
one[10,5:30:1] = 1
# Here I'd like to count 25 from both directions

two = background.copy()    # diagonal line, this stands for all angles the diagonal line could have, not just 45degrees!
two[[range(10,35)],[range(5,30)]] = 1
# Here I'd like to count 25 from both directions

three = background.copy()   # line with right angle
three[10,5:15:1] = 1
three[10:25:1,15] = 1
# Here I'd like to count 10 from one end and 15 from the other

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
fig = plt.figure()
line = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
diag = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
angle = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
line.imshow(one), line.set_title('Count 25 from both sides')
diag.imshow(two), diag.set_title('Count 25 from both sides')
angle.imshow(three), angle.set_title('Count 10 from one side and 15 from the other')
```

[image]
My problem is that I don't even know what to google.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say "all 2D directions", do you mean the 8 "obvious" directions, or do you want to include other intermediate directions too? (They differ from the 8 cardinal directions in that for those the centres of the relevant pixels are literally on a straight line.)

Comment: What exactly is the output that you want? If you put in an input with lines of various lengths in various directions, do you want just the length of the longest line, or the length of the longest line in each direction, or the lengths of *all* lines, or what?

Comment: What can you tell us about what you need this for? (That might make a difference to how much efficiency matters, for instance.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: 
First question: I mean ALL directions, not only the obvious ones.
Second question: I want the length of ALL (=2) the lines (and the information where that line started to count)
Third question: I am trying to write a program that can detect the orientation of a maggot in a movie (1200frames per movie). As the tail of the maggot seems to be straight more often than the head, I was thinking of using the straight line as an indicator for the tail

Comment: If you google "straight line detection" you will find some information about this sort of thing; one particularly common approach is called the "Hough transform". The focus is usually on identifying approximately-straight lines of reasonable length, which sounds pretty close to what you're after, rather than counting pixels as such.

Comment: If you're trying to identify something that isn't necessarily very close to straight, you might instead consider looking for "connected components" and seeing if there are any that look maggoty enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gareth (see comments of my question) I was able to figure this out. The Hough transformation is the solution I was looking for.

Scipy has a function to do this. The documentation can be found [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.transform.html#probabilistic-hough-line) and a nice demonstration and explanation can be found [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_line_hough_transform.html).

I implemented the solution into the question above. I also added one example where one of the pixels/ones is not on a straight line, but 'straight enough'. This can be influenced by the parameters of the `probabilistic_hough_line` function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
from skimage.transform import probabilistic_hough_line

background = np.zeros((60,60))

one = background.copy() # straight line
one[10,5:30:1] = 1
# Here I'd like to count 25 from both directions

two = background.copy()    # diagonal line, this stands for all angles the diagonal line could have, not just 45degrees!
two[[range(10,35)],[range(5,30)]] = 1
# Here I'd like to count 25 from both directions

three = background.copy()   # line with right angle
three[10,5:15:1] = 1
three[10:25:1,15] = 1
# Here I'd like to count 10 from one end and 15 from the other

four = background.copy()    # line with one value out of place and a right angle
four[10,5:8:1] = 1
four[11,8] = 1
four[10,9:15] = 1
four[10:25:1,15] = 1
# Here I'd like to count 10 from one side and 15 from the other side

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,2)
fig = plt.figure()
line_plt = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
diag = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
angle = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0])
angle_dirty = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
line_plt.imshow(one), line_plt.set_title('Count 25 from both sides')
diag.imshow(two), diag.set_title('Count 25 from both sides')
angle.imshow(three), angle.set_title('Count 10 from one side and 15 from the other')
angle_dirty.imshow(four), angle_dirty.set_title('Count 10 from one side and 15 from the other')

# This function returns the  List of lines identified, lines in format ((x0, y0), (x1, y0)), indicating line start and end.
lines_one = probabilistic_hough_line(one, threshold=10, line_length=5, line_gap=3)
# Now to the plotting on top of the original image
for line in lines_one:
    p0, p1 = line
    line_plt.plot((p0[0], p1[0]), (p0[1], p1[1]))

lines_two = probabilistic_hough_line(two, threshold=10, line_length = 5, line_gap = 3)
for line in lines_two:
    p0, p1 = line
    diag.plot((p0[0], p1[0]), (p0[1], p1[1]))

lines_three = probabilistic_hough_line(three, threshold=10, line_length = 5, line_gap = 3)
for line in lines_three:
    p0, p1 = line
    angle.plot((p0[0], p1[0]), (p0[1], p1[1]))

lines_four = probabilistic_hough_line(four, threshold=10, line_length = 5, line_gap = 3)
for line in lines_four:
    p0, p1 = line
    angle_dirty.plot((p0[0], p1[0]), (p0[1], p1[1]))
```

[image]